# Is there a way to edit the fonts of headings without a plugin (in the 2022 theme)?

Tags: css, theme-twenty-twenty-two

I couldn't figure out how to change the font of the headings and the body after changing themes back to the default. (I feel like I had done it and then when I changed to a different theme and then back my customizations were lost and I couldn't figure out how to re-customize). So, I installed a plugin (but I feel like this is such a basic change). Am I missing something? How do I set basic styling like the font and size of a heading (H1, H2, H3, etc)?

Edit: I'm using the Twenty-Twenty-Two theme and hoping to import the google fonts without a plugin and also to make the H1, H2, body, ..etc.. styles consistent throughout the site and use those instead of modifying everything separately.

For reference this is the site I'm trying to create (it's currently only one page but will grow to be several pages)
https://nationalparksatoz.com

Comment: You can `@import` font-family (if it's not added already) and then write custom CSS to headings, and body (eg. `h1 {font-family: 'xxx'; font-size: 32px;}`).

Comment: Are you using a child theme? Put your CSS in your style.css. ex: h1 { font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;font-size: 16px;}

Comment: Ok.. so the font import should just work without the plugin?
Where do I edit the global styles for my WP instance?
It's not obvious to me the way a typical html + css site would be. 
Thanks!!

Comment: After much frustration I've gone back to the plug-in ... I give up.

Answer (score 1):

if your are using child theme, you can edit your style.css and make you css code override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element!.

```
h1 {
 font-family: 'xxx' !important;
 font-size: 32px !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try... Questions I still have are:
Is Twenty-Twenty-Two a child theme? 
Where do I edit the main H1 style?

Comment: @pixelfairy You can create a child theme for any theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: sorry...I tried for an hour and I'm still stuck

Comment: I added this to style.css
        
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@600@display=swap');
       
and lower down
       
h1 {
 font-family: "Cabin", sans-serif !important;
}

Comment: comments don't support line breaks... hard to communicate here

Comment: @pixelfairy can you share you website link and your theme name ?